# LibGDX Generating a png from a model

Tags: libgdx

The title pretty much say it all, I need to get a image from a `Model` is this posible? I searched for this and found nothing.

Solution thanks to @retodaredevil

```
    FrameBuffer fbo   = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA4444, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
    ModelBatch  batch = new ModelBatch();

    fbo.begin(); // make fbo the current buffer

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0,screenWidth, screenHeight);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin(camera);
    batch.render(instance, environment);
    batch.end();

    try{
        FileHandle fh = new FileHandle(output);
        Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fbo.end(); // Now you can draw on the display again

    batch.dispose();
    fbo.dispose();
```

Comment: Add more information, what do you have and what do you want?

Comment: Are you wanting to get a raw texture that the model uses to render itself or are you wanting to get an image of the model being rendered?

Comment: I want an image of the model being rendered but what do you mean by a raw texture? If i can get a Texture i can get its pixmap and i can make a png file from it

Comment: From what I understand (I haven't used models before) models are a representation of a 3d object. A model is made of of images and has some sort of structure to define how it's rendered. I'm wondering if you want the final render of what the model looks like or if you just want the images that make up the model.

Comment: I want a final render, and it to consider the environment lights

Comment: And you want to use the model and environment to create a Texture or Pixmap to then save to a file instead of rendering it to the screen? Can you post a little code on what you have set up right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, we'll have to use two different tutorials

https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/FrameBufferObjects

https://xoppa.github.io/blog/basic-3d-using-libgdx/ (You're probably already familiar with this)

```
FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA4444, width, height, hasDepth);
// I've never used a FrameBuffer before so you may have to play around with constructor parameters

ModelBatch batch = // your ModelBatch initialization here

fbo.begin(); // make fbo the current buffer
glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.resize(fbo.getWidth(), fbo.getHeight());

batch.begin();
batch.render(modelInstance, environment);
batch.end();

fbo.end(); // Now you can draw on the display again

// If you want to, you can resize your batch and use it to draw on the display
batch.resize(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
```

<strike>Once you do whatever you need to do to your FrameBuffer, you can get the texture</strike>

```
fbo.getTexture();
```

EDIT: That method doesn't exist, look at OP's question for solution
EDIT 2: FrameBuffer does actually have a method called getColorBufferTexture()

For saving a texture, look at https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8358#p8358 or https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5686

I used this to get one of the links: [Libgdx save SpriteBatch in a texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731463/libgdx-save-spritebatch-in-a-texture) everything else I duckduckgoed

If something doesn't work let me know and I can try to look around more.

Comment: Thanks! this led me to the right place! I will award my bounty to you in 3 hours

Comment: @centenond glad I could help. If you have any other links that helped you definitely comment them or edit your answer for future people that come across this.