# How to get a BufferedImage from a Pixmap in libGDX?

Tags: bitmap, libgdx, bufferedimage, pixmap

I have a Pixmap (libGDX Class) and would like to convert this into a BufferedImage.
Is this possible and if so how to do this ?

There is only one method that seems to be the gate to do that, but I have no idea how. Any hints ?

```
pixmap.getPixels()
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient, but if you don't care about wasting resources encoding the data as PNG in an internal buffer, you can do this:

```java
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Pixmap pixmap) throws IOException {
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        PixmapIO.PNG writer = new PixmapIO.PNG(pixmap.getWidth() * pixmap.getHeight() * 4);
        try {
            writer.setFlipY(false);
            writer.setCompression(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);
            writer.write(baos, pixmap);
        } finally {
            writer.dispose();
        }

        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
new ImageIcon(pixmap.getPixels().array()).getImage();
```

One thing you may have to watch out for, is the [Pixmap.Format](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.Format.html). I believe that that could alter the array of bytes created.

To be honest, I'm not sure if the above code works, but I hope it points you in the right direction.

References:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/CreatingaBufferedImagefromanImageobject.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried, but I get an "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" and I am not sure, if my approach is correct. In the end I would like to have a rotated Pixmap without drawing, so I can read the pixeldata of the rotated Pixmap. Do you know how to do that ? My approach was to convert into Imagebuffer and rotate, but maybe thats not the correct way to do .

Comment: @mcflysoft you mention without drawing, I answered a question a few days ago that might help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939146/